# Hit json url link to check any new data after a certain time in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I need to hit json url every one week to check new data.I tried this way.

First I take the lunching time in milisecond and save it to in a plist,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

long currentTime = (long)(NSTimeInterval)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
    NSDictionary * dict =[NSMutableDictionary new];
    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"time.plist"];
    [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:currentTime] forKey:@"count"];
    [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Then I check it in background .If 7 days are gone,I fire a timer to hit the json url.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"json.plist"];

    NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    long plistTime= [[plistDictionary objectForKey:@"count"] longValue];
    timeWithSevenDays=plistTime+604800;
     timer =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeWithSevenDays
                                               target: self
                                             selector: @selector(checkForUpdateJson)
                                             userInfo: nil
                                              repeats: YES];
    [timer fire];

}
```

After firing timer,I update plist data with current time. But if the application in foreground in 7 days, it create a complexity.

Should I use a background service for it ? But background service is decrease battery life.
Or any efficient way to add it into Appdelegate that works foreground and background.

Comment: Why don't you do it when the app comes to foreground, so you know the user is interested?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the new data in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Alternative is to have a push notification server to let the user know there's new content and download it when app becomes active.

Comment: You really don't want to use this method. `applicationWillEnterForeground:` would be much better.

Comment: `applicationDidBecomeActive` can be called a lot more than `applicationWillEnterForeground` including while the app is still being used and some system alert comes and goes.